# What does Gryz's "Crash" skill do?

Tags: phantasy-star-4

Phantasy Star IV does not include any in-game help about techniques or skills, so I've resorted to keeping a [PDF version of the manual](http://gazetadealgol.com.br/_media/diversos/scans/scan-ps4_manual.pdf) always open on my tablet while playing. Thing is, Gryz's "Crash" skill is not explained in the manual.

Does anyone know what this skill does?

Thanks.

Comment: [This FAQ might be helpful to you](http://www.gamefaqs.com/genesis/563334-phantasy-star-iv/faqs/31907), since I know you commented in another question that you are curious about many skills.

Comment: @Sterno Yeah, I had posted another question, but was told I was requesting too much information, so I deleted it. The FAQ you provided looks to be very comprehensive, I'll probably refer to it instead of the manual. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (and I found a reference [here](http://phantasystar.wikia.com/wiki/Skills_in_Phantasy_Star_IV:_The_End_of_the_Millennium)), Crash is a skill that has a chance to take out an enemy.

Comment: This is correct - it's a very low chance instant kill.  Basically totally worthless IMO

Comment: @Shinrai I agree, you end up craping an enemy before actually having the chance to instant him.

Comment: @Gamb nice find, I'll put that page and the [Techniques one](http://phantasystar.wikia.com/wiki/Techniques_in_Phantasy_Star_IV:_The_End_of_the_Millennium) in my bookmarks. Thanks!

Comment: @fernio anytime, pal.